# Passing List Info to New Activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I'm building on a tutorial I did in which I created a `RecyclerView` screen with cards with selectable options. I want one of the selectable options to bring the user to a new `activity` that has more information & options about the card they selected. My problem is when I try to transfer traits of that specific card to the next `SlideViewActivity.java` `activity` I am unable to successfully do so. I tried transforming my list into an `array` then sending that, but I keep obtaining a `null` value (which could be due to my syntax for all I know).

Any clarification & guidance would be appreciated, let me know if you would want any of the other code as well.

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private List<Properties> dogList;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title, count;
    public ImageView thumbnail, overflow;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
        thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        overflow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.overflow);
    }
}

public Adapter(Context mContext, List<Properties> dogList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.dogList = dogList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Properties dog = dogList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(dog.getName());
    // loading dog cover using Glide library
    Glide.with(mContext).load(dog.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);
    holder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showPopupMenu(holder.overflow);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Showing popup menu when tapping on icon
 */
private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
    // inflate menu
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener());
    popup.show();
}

/**
 * Click listener for popup menu items
 */
class MyMenuItemClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

    public MyMenuItemClickListener() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add_favourite:
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Add to favourite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_more_info:
                Intent slideStart = new Intent(mContext, SlideViewActivity.class);
                String[] dogArray = new String[dogList.size()];
                slideStart.putExtra("List", dogArray);
                Log.e("putting extra", String.valueOf(dogArray[0]));
                //TODO:MAKE NAME TRANSFERS WORK
                mContext.startActivity(slideStart);
                return true;
            default:
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Adding Properties.java:

```
public class Properties {
private String name;
private String info;
private int thumbnail;

public Properties() {
}

public Properties(String name, String info, int thumbnail) {
    this.name = name;
    this.info = info;
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getInfo() {
    return info;
}

public void getInfo(String info) {
    this.info = info;
}

public int getThumbnail() {
    return thumbnail;
}

public void setThumbnail(int thumbnail) {
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `ArrayList<T>`, if `T` is `Serializable`.

for example:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
intent.putExtra("list", list);
```

use `getSerializableExtra` to extract data

Comment: I found this way to be the simplest - able to get size but having trouble getting name values but that's probably my syntax at this point. I'll let you know if I have major problems after trying a bit more, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your array is `dogList.size()`-d null values.

```
String[] dogArray = new String[dogList.size()];
slideStart.putExtra("List", dogArray);
```

You should see `null` logged here.

```
Log.e("putting extra", String.valueOf(dogArray[0]));
```

It's not clear what type of class you have for `Properties`, but if it is your class, and not `java.util.Properties`, [you should implement `Parcelable` on that class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-parcelable), then you'd have

```
intent.putParcelableArrayList("List", dogList)
```

(**Tip**: You should rename that class to `Dog` to avoid confusion for yourself and others)

But if you are just worried about getting null, case matters. You put a key=`"List"`, so make sure you aren't getting key=`"list"` or anything else but `"List"`

Answer (score 0):

Two ways possible for that::

1. **First**

While Sending the list using intent::

```
Intent slideStart = new Intent(mContext, SlideViewActivity.class);
slideStart.putExtra("List", dogList);
mContext.startActivity(slideStart);
```

In This just pass the list as is it is ::

But your class `Properties` should be implements **"Serializable"**

Now while receiving that intent ::

```
ArrayList<Properties> dogList =(ArrayList<Properties>) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("List");
```

1. **Second way** :: using  Library

One library is there for converting string to arraylist & vice versa ,

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
```

So, for this while sending list convert that list to string like ::

```
Type listType  = new TypeToken<List<Properties>>() {
                        }.getType();
String listString=new Gson().toJson(dogList,listType );
```

pass this simple as string with intent:::

```
Intent slideStart = new Intent(mContext, SlideViewActivity.class);
slideStart.putExtra("List", listString);
mContext.startActivity(slideStart);
```

And while getting it back in other activity::

```
 String listString =getIntent().getExtras().getString("List");
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Properties>>() {}.getType();
 List<Properties> list=new Gson().fromJson(listString, listType);
```

Tell me if need more help..

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar project I will share my code. Please take a look and if have doubts ping me

**DataAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.vishnum.indiavideo;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    List<Video_Details> video;

    public DataAdapter(List<Video_Details> video, Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.video = video;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_row, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Video_Details videoDetails =  video.get(position);
        String url;
        final String VideoID;

        holder.title.setText(video.get(position).getTitle());

        VideoID= video.get(position).getV_id();
        url = video.get(position).getThumb();

         Glide.with(context)
                 .load(url)
                 .override(150,70)
                 .into(holder.thumb);
       //viewHolder.thumb.setText(android.get(i).getVer());
      //  viewHolder.tv_api_level.setText(android.get(i).getApi());

        holder.vm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onClick(View v) {
                                             Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "You Clicked"+video.get(position).getV_id(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                             Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),Play_Video.class);
                                             intent.putExtra("VideoId",(video.get(position).getV_id()));
                                             intent.putExtra("Title",(video.get(position).getTitle()));
                                             v.getContext().startActivity(intent);


                                         }
                                     }

        );
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return video.size();
    }




    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView title;
        public ImageView thumb;
        public String videoid;
        public View vm;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            vm = view;
            title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            thumb = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumb);



            //tv_version = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_version);
            //tv_api_level = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_api_level);

        }
    }


}
```

**Video_Details.java**

```
package com.example.vishnum.indiavideo;
public class Video_Details {
    private String id;
    private String v_id;
    private String title;
    private String thumb;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getV_id() {
        return v_id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getThumb() {
        return (Constants.urlvideo+v_id+"/0.jpg");
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setV_id(String v_id) {
        this.v_id = v_id;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setThumb(String v_id) {
        this.thumb =Constants.urlvideo+v_id+"/0.jpg";
    }
}
```